# Difference between "flavourful" and "flavoursome"?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, differences

What is the difference between *flavourful* and *flavoursome*?

I was reading a packet of raisins, which described the raisins as ***flavourful***. I didn't recognise that word. Is it less common than ***flavoursome***?

The [Merriam-Webster dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/flavor) just lists them both as adjectives, without elucidating further.

Answer (score 2):

> Earlier *flavorsome* (1853), *flavory* (1727), *flavorous* (1690s).

Today, it's [*flavorful* (1904)](https://www.etymonline.com/word/flavorful).

*Flavoursome* may still be found in British English writing and *flavorsome* rarely in some AmE.

[Google nGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=flavoursome%2Cflavorsome%2Cflavourful%2Cflavorful&year_start=1920&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cflavoursome%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cflavorsome%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cflavourful%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cflavorful%3B%2Cc0) "flavoursome,flavorsome,flavourful,flavorful; 1920-2000; **English**.

[image: Google nGram "flavoursome,flavorsome,flavourful,flavorful"; 1920-2000.]

[Google nGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=flavoursome%2Cflavorsome%2Cflavourful%2Cflavorful&year_start=1920&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cflavoursome%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cflavorsome%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cflavourful%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cflavorful%3B%2Cc0) "flavoursome,flavorsome,flavourful,flavorful; 1920-2000; **British English**.

[image]

Comment: Note that the first graph, made for 'English' is for all sources of English, not simply American English. If you do the search for just American English (for a one-to-one comparison with British English), it turns out that AmE has a very similar (almost identical?) distribution to the more inclusive 'English'. This could be because 'all' English is more similar to AmE than BrE, or it could be because there are way more AmE texts/instances than BrE.

Comment: Following on from @Mithc's comment, it's also worth noting the different scales in your two graphs. "Flavorful" in AmE usage is an order of magnitude more common than any of the options in BrE usage. Or, put another way, none of these words are common in BrE. I suspect we'd be much more likely to use "tasty".

Comment: @AndyT *Taste* vs. *Flavo(u)r* as a moot point is as old as the hills. AFAIK they're distinct.

Answer (score 2):

The [British National Corpus](https://www.english-corpora.org/bnc/) contains the following words beginning *flavour* (slightly manipulated to combine the same word with or without trailing punctuation):

```
FLAVOUR                1467
FLAVOURS                280
FLAVOURED               245
FLAVOURING               70
FLAVOURINGS              34
FLAVOURSOME              20
FLAVOUR-AVERSION         13
FLAVOURFUL                9
FLAVOURLESS               7
FLAVOUR-OF-THE-MONTH      4
FLAVOURISTS               1
FLAVOURED'MOST            1
FLAVOUR-TESTED            1
FLAVOUR-ENHANCING         1
```

The [Corpus of Contemporary American English](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/) has a *lot* of words beginning *flavor*. Some of them are clearly bad data (e.g. FLAVOR-WAS is really *flavor - was*). Others are clearly brand names (e.g. FLAVORWIRE). One is a personal name from a sci-fi book (FLAVORIUS).

```
FLAVOR                11899
FLAVORS                5040
FLAVORED               1388
FLAVORFUL              1082
FLAVORING               416
FLAVORINGS              223
FLAVORLESS              109
FLAVOR-PACKED            45
FLAVOR-OF-THE-MONTH      14
FLAVORIST                13
FLAVORSOME               12
FLAVOR-ENHANCING          8
FLAVORIZER                7
FLAVOR-FILLED             6
FLAVORISTS                5
FLAVOR-RICH               4
FLAVOR-WISE               4
FLAVOR-BOOSTING           3
FLAVOROUS                 3
FLAVOR-BOMB               2
FLAVOR-ENHANCED           2
FLAVOR-ENGINEERING        2
FLAVOR-GIVING             2
FLAVOR-FORWARD            2
FLAVOR-TRIPPING           2
FLAVOR-INTENSE            2
FLAVOR-INFUSED            2
FLAVORED-IN               2
FLAVORIZED                2
FLAVORWISE                2
```

and a whole stack of hapax legomena, most of which should really count towards plain `FLAVOR`.

If we filter those down to words which seem to have similar meanings to *flavourful* and *flavoursome* we get

BNC:

```
FLAVOURSOME              20
FLAVOURFUL                9
```

COCA:

```
FLAVORFUL              1082
FLAVOR-PACKED            45
FLAVORSOME               12
FLAVOR-FILLED             6
FLAVOR-RICH               4
FLAVOROUS                 3
FLAVOR-FORWARD            2
FLAVOR-INFUSED            2
```

The proportions are similar to the Google NGrams data in @Kris' answer: *flavorful* predominates in US English, and is quite common. *Flavoursome* is about twice as common as *flavourful* in British English, but they're both rare.